# What should File Inspector's default app be to open files with no extensions, like .zprofile?

Tags: finder, applications

I'd like to use "*File Inspector*" to quickly check config files like .zshrc, .viminfo, and also server config files elsewhere. But these types of files never have extensions which seems to mess-up *File Inspector* ability to open it and give me a quick view of the contents.

**/usr/bin/vim** as the default app is exactly what I'd want, but only apps in the *Applications* folder are offered as choices.

Am I supposed to install a *vim* app (in addition to /usr/bin/vim) from the **App Store**? And is it even possible to configure "*File Inspector*" to open files with no extension by default with **vim**?

Comment: It’s important to remember that not all files without an extension are text files.  Setting a default for this could cause issues going forward

Comment: Don't these files have no names just an extension. Also yes you need an app e.g. MacVim not a command line tool

Comment: @mmmmmm For each config file, were I to create a hard link with a .txt extension in the same directory, that satisfies File Inspector whose Finder "quick view" utility intrigues me. I've got a new mac and don't want to mess it up. If creating those shadow hard links sounds like a bad idea, other than creating file clutter, please warn me.

Comment: @mmmmmm Does switching default editors also enable QuickLook in Finder (which I assume the OP has in mind when talking about "File Inspector")?

Comment: sorry don't know - I suspect not - at least with my setup which is emacs